# NHibernate Criteria Sorting from one-to-many relationship (list property)

Tags: nhibernate, sorting, criteria, one-to-many

I have an Effort entity and a Schedule entity.
The Schedule entity represents the page on wich Efforts are displayed.
Each Effort can have a separate Order on each Schedule page.

So the best DB structure for this case would look like this

Effort -> ScheduleOrder(with position) <- Schedule
so the one-to-many and many-to-one.

Now I need to sort Efforts on page usig NHibernate criteria.

So I need to use something like property that returns Position for each Schedule.
I can acheave this by using DB View or Property with customised Select query.

Anyone has an idea how to do sorting from one-to-many relationship in a better way?

Answer (score 0):

with

```
class ScheduleOrder
{
    public virtual Effort Effort { get; set; }
    public virtual Schedule Schedule { get; set; }
    public virtual int Position { get; set; }
}

var efforts = session.CreateCriteria<ScheduleOrder>()
    .Add(Expression.Eq("Schedule", schedule))
    .AddOrder(Order.Asc("Position"))
    .SetFetchMode("Effort", FetchMode.Eager)
    .List()
    .Select(so => so.Effort);
```

or with

```
class Schedule
{
    // LIst has a position
    public virtual IList<Effort> Efforts { get; set; }
}

HasMany(x => x.Efforts)
    .AsList("position");
// or
HasManyToMany(x => x.Efforts)
    .AsList("position");


// schedule.Efforts have the right order
```